# UITabBarItem's title does not shown when using with Navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm having a trouble with my very simple app.

My app simply have 2 mains `UIViewControllers` called News and Category, each of them has their own `UINavigationController`.

So in `AppDelegate.swift`, I've done like this

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

let newsVC = NewsVC()

// CREATE TAB BAR ITEM WITH TITLE ONLY
let newsVCTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "News", image: nil, tag: 1)
newsVC.tabBarItem = newsVCTabBarItem

let categoryVC = CategoryVC()

// CREATE TAB BAR ITEM WITH TITLE ONLY
let categoryVCTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Category", image: nil, tag: 2)
categoryVC.tabBarItem = categoryVCTabBarItem

let rootViewControllers = [newsVC, categoryVC]

// CREATE NAVIGATION CONTROLLER FOR EACH OF THEM
tabBarController.viewControllers = rootViewControllers.map {
    UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
}
window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

When I run this simple application, the tab bar items do not show anything :(

But when I change the `UITabBarItem` to system's styles like this

```
let newsVCTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .featured, tag: 1)
```

It's working perfectly! So hard to understand!

So does anyone know why my title-only tab bar item does not working? Have I missed something important?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to set the tabBarItem after put the viewcontroller in UINavigationController.

Comment: I've tried your idea, but it's still does not work :(, anw, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `title` property to the `ViewController`s to show the title in `UITabBarItem`.

```
var title: String? { get set }
```

> Set the title to a human-readable string that describes the view. **If
>   the view controller has a valid navigation item or tab-bar item,
>   assigning a value to this property updates the title text of those
>   objects.**

```
let newsVC = ViewController()
newsVC.title = "News"

.....

let categoryVC = ViewController2()
categoryVC.title = "Category"

.....
```

Or

Assign an image to the `UITabBarItem` to see the result.

```
let newsVCTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "News", image: UIImage(named: "news.png"), tag: 1)

....

let categoryVCTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Category", image: UIImage(named: "category.png"), tag: 2)

.....
```

**Update:**

> Tab bar items are configured through their corresponding view
>   controller. To associate a tab bar item with a view controller, create
>   a new instance of the UITabBarItem class, configure it appropriately
>   for the view controller, and assign it to the view controller’s
>   tabBarItem property. **If you don't provide a custom tab bar item for
>   your view controller, the view controller creates a default item
>   containing no image and the text from the view controller’s title
>   property.**

Comment: Cool! It's worked, but I still confusing, if I set the view controller's title different from the ui tab bar item, it show the VC's title (but not the one I've set in ui tab bar item), so the name in ui tab bar item seem useless?

Comment: Yes it is. If we do not provide the image for the tabBarItem it takes title property of ViewController. So, the first answer only shows the title of the tabBarItem. If we provide image along with title then UITabBarController considers UITabBarItems.

Comment: Very glad to help you and even I too forgot why its not working for a moment .

Comment: Any clue with it doesn't show my custom title for the bar when using for example `UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .featured, tag: 0)`? It shows as tab bar title "Featured" instead of my custom title, despite setting `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController` titles.